# Passing class as a parameter c++

Tags: c++

im new to programming and just start learning C++ a few weeks, im current doing the random number stuff, but i don't understand why the parameters sometime has "()" and sometime doesn't, hope someone can explain to me, thanks!.

```
int main()
{
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 rdn(rd()); //Why this parameter needs "()"?
    uniform_int_distribution<int> maxrd(1, 5000);
    
    int n = maxrd(rdn); //And why this parameter doesn't need "()"?

    cout << n;
};
```

Comment: In `rd()` we're calling the `std::random_device::operator()` and passing the returned value as an argument to `mt19937`'s constructor. This is explained in any [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Accessing the parameter value itself never requires `()`. Using `()` means invoking `operator()` on that variables (assuming the variable is of a class that has an `operator()`).

Comment: A side note: you `main()` should return some `int` value (since the return value is `int`, not `void`). A value of `0` indicates that `main` completed without errors.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to not explicitly return a value from `main`, and some prefer it this way for toy examples because it reduces clutter. The standard will return 0 in such cases. This does not apply to any other functions. Only `main`.

Comment: @paddy thanks. Good to know. However I still believe returning an explicit `0` is somewhat better practice.

Comment: That is a style choice and entirely down to potentially divisive personal preference. I happen to prefer omitting it, unless I'm constructing a program that intends to return actual status values.

Comment: @StephenNewell that was my mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### Case 1

```
mt19937 rdn(rd());
```

In the above statement, `rd()` uses(calls) the overloaded `std::random_device::operator()` and then the return value from that is used as an argument to `mt19937`'s constructor.

Basically the parenthesis `()` is used to call the `operator()` of `std::random_device`. That is, here the parenthesis `()` after the `rd` are there because we want to pass the returned value from `rd()` as argument and not `rd` itself.

##### Case 2

```
int n = maxrd(rdn);
```

In the above statement, we're calling `std::uniform_int_distribution::operator()` which takes a `Generator` as argument and so we're passing `rdn` as an argument since `rdn` is already a generator.

Note here we're **not** using `()` after `rdn` because we want to pass `rdn` as argument and not the returned value from `rdn()`.